# Muting an application from terminal in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, audio

Is there a method to mute applications from terminal?

I know `amixer` will work for muting everything; but is there a simple solution for muting just a given application, from terminal?

Answer (score 3):

If your Linux uses `pulseaudio`, this is what you need:

1. Examine the output of `pacmd list-sink-inputs` and find the application you want to mute; note its index.
2. Run `pacmd set-sink-input-mute <index> true` to mute the application (`… false` to unmute).

Example (some irrelevant lines replaced by `…`):

```
$ pacmd list-sink-inputs
    index: 0
…
    index: 1
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        flags: START_CORKED FIX_RATE 
        state: RUNNING
        sink: 0 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        volume: front-left: 95027 / 145% / 9,68 dB,   front-right: 95027 / 145% / 9,68 dB
                balance 0,00
        muted: no
        current latency: 1952,72 ms
        requested latency: 40,00 ms
        sample spec: float32le 2 k 44100 Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        resample method: copy
        module: 10
        client: 8 <VLC media player (LibVLC 2.2.2)>
        properties:
                media.role = "video"
                media.name = "audio stream"
                application.name = "VLC media player (LibVLC 2.2.2)"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "30"
                application.id = "org.VideoLAN.VLC"
                application.version = "2.2.2"
                application.icon_name = "vlc"
                application.language = "pl_PL.UTF-8"
                application.process.id = "15133"
…
$ pacmd set-sink-input-mute 1 true    # mutes VLC
$ pacmd set-sink-input-mute 1 false   # unmutes VLC
```

---

There is [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180661/693277) with the following script that allows you to mute or unmute an application by its name:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> main() {
>     local action=mute
>     while getopts :hu option; do 
>         case "$option" in 
>             h) usage 0 ;;
>             u) action=unmute ;;
>             ?) usage 1 "invalid option: -$OPTARG" ;;
>         esac
>     done
>     shift $((OPTIND - 1))
>
>     if [[ "$1" ]]; then
>         $action "$1"
>     else
>         usage 1 "specify an application name" 
>     fi
> }
>
> usage() {
>     [[ "$2" ]] && echo "error: $2"
>     echo "usage: $0 [-h] [-u] appname"
>     echo "where: -u = ummute application (default action is to mute)"
>     exit $1
> }
>
> mute()   { adjust_muteness "$1" 1; }
> unmute() { adjust_muteness "$1" 0; }
>
> adjust_muteness() { 
>     local index=$(get_index "$1")
>     [[ "$index" ]] && pacmd set-sink-input-mute "$index" $2 >/dev/null 
> }
>
> get_index() {
>     local pid=$(pidof "$1")
>     if [[ -z "$pid" ]]; then
>         echo "error: no running processes for: $1" >&2
>     else
>         pacmd list-sink-inputs | 
>         awk -v pid=$pid '
>             $1 == "index:" {idx = $2} 
>             $1 == "application.process.id" && $3 == "\"" pid "\"" {print idx; exit}
>         '
>     fi
> }
>
> main "$@"
> ```

If it works for you then please upvote [the original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180661/693277).

Answer (score 0):

Or just use pa_control if scripting is not useful:

https://github.com/rhaas80/pa_volume

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can elaborate on this a little more?